# How to check if Mac and Linux have secure boot enabled and disabled via command line?

Tags: command-line, c#, secure-boot

I am writing a program in Net Core and it seems like getting this information via the Terminal is the only way.

So how to check if Mac and Linux have secure boot enabled and disabled via command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on most GNU/linux distros, you can check if secure boot is enabled with the following command

```
mokutil --sb-state
```

Apple uses their own bootloader, which only boots into MacOS, so *secure boot* isn't really a thing on Macintosh computers.

Comment: macOS Mojave... `-bash: mokutil: command not found`

Comment: @Tetsujin The command is for GNU/Linux only. Please read the answer again, carefully.

Comment: I was just pointing out that not only is secure boot "not a thing" on mac, you can't even ask about it from terminal.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, it's a GNU/Linux utility, not for Unix or MacOS, so that's kinda obvious, right?

Comment: @rahuldottech I appreciate the answer. very helpful. The only reason I ask for mac is because I found this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330

Comment: @Danny You're welcome. Secure Boot in the context of Apple devices means something very different from what it means in the case of Windows or GNU/Linux (where it's a UEFI thing), and unfortunately there appears to be no way to check its functioning from terminal.

Comment: @rahuldottech I can finally have closure on mac part, it was worth a try.

Comment: @Danny Yeah... Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 0):

okay this guy means Apple Secure Boot: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330

This is not the SecureBoot that you get from windows!
So This answer with an green checkmark is not helpful